# UIButton titleLabel truncates or wraps to size of button image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, interface-builder

I can't figure out why this is but it seems that the title "Attach Photo" truncates or wraps to about the size of the image added to the UIButton displayed below.

Is there any way to get the title to not wrap? The button itself is much larger than the length of the text.

[image]

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Answer (score 0):

Check the button's subviews at runtime to see what the button's label's `numberOfLines` is set to; `0` will make it auto-wrap. `UIButton` specifically provides access to `titleLabel` so that you can change its properties (per the docs), so try changing that.

Comment: Setting the `numberOfLines` to `1` keeps it on one line but then clips the `titleLabel`.

Comment: What happens after a call to `sizeToFit` on the label?

Comment: Nothing changed, the label is still clipped.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was changing the `right` edge inset vs changing the `left` edge inset. `left` adjusts the `origin.x` value, whereas, `right` adjusts both `origin.x` and `size.width`. So the `right` value I specified in interface builder was being subtracted from the `titleLabel`'s overall width.